# Encoding of a Sybase exported file

Tags: encoding, sybase

I need to import a csv file (comma-separated values) with an unknown encoding. All I know is that the file has been created using an export from a Sybase database (but I don't know what kind of Sybase), but any encoding I tried gives me wrong results.

Anyone here who can help me identify the correct encoding?

For Example:

- The German Umlaut "ä" (`&auml;`) is encoded as hex "D9"
- The German Umlaut "ö" (`&ouml;`) is encoded as hex "F0"
- The German Umlaut "ü" (`&uuml;`) is encoded as hex "F6"

I couldn't find any encoding that fits those examples...

I have no access to that Sybase system, and I cannot change the export, so I have to deal with that encoding "as is".

I tried all encodings that C# has available, but is not any of the know encodings.

Any ideas or sources?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? who created the file and what have they told you re: how the file was created (eg, did they use `bcp` and if so did they use `bcp -n` or `bcp -c`)? if you're on a linux system what does `file filename` say? have you tried a hex dump and review of the first 30-100 lines to see if there's anything of use in the file header (eg, `od -c filename | head -40`)?

Comment: The file is a simple CSV file, comma-separated values. All I know is that it was created using a Sybase database. The customer can't tell me any more details.

Comment: *The customer can't tell me any more details.* ... really?  something doesn't sound/smell right as the customer is the one who created the file, right? what does `od -c filename | head -10` show? (update the question with the `od` output)

Comment: Customer is just a user, not a programmer. He didn't create the export routine himself, this is why I have to possibility to change that export. The file is a simple plain ascii csv file, that can be read in any text editor. the "od" shows nothing else that the plain ascii. All characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, etc. are readable, just special non-ascii characters (like the German umlauts) have an unknown encoding like shown above.

Comment: can the client tell you anything about the character set the database is running under? or any options the 'export routine' has for encoding the output file? how did you come to know the D9/F0/F6 characters are german umlauts (ie, any chance that mappings are incorrect)?

Comment: The content of the CSV is a list of names and postal addresses. I can read the text, and I can see that for example all Umlaut characters are wrong. Using a hex editor I can see what hex code is used for the expected character. Just that simple. So instead of `Gebäude` the file contains `GebÙude` -- the `ä` is `Ù` in the file -- hex code "D9".